# geofire query not refreshing the longitude and latitude on location change

Tags: android, firebase, geofire

This is a geofire query I am using. It is sending the longitude and latitude to firebase, but is not refreshing the longitude and latitude of the location change. Even am using this in on location change method of map activity.

```
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(current_user_db);         
geoFire.setLocation(
  userid, 
  new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),
  new GeoFire.CompletionListener(){
    @Override public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {}
  }
);
```

Comment: This code writes a single location to the database. It doesn't actually query Geofire, so it won't respond to any changes. To listen for change, use a GeoQuery as shown here: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#geo-queries

Comment: still in which key method should i use the statement to update the location in firebase.. and which statement...??